# Php Query into database Fail?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to insert data into my database that is setup like this

### Table

- name     varchar(35)
- department varchar(50)
- rating smallint(6)
- easiness  smallint(6)
- textbook  varchar(3)
- timestamp     timestamp
- course    char(10)
- curve     char(3)
- comment   text

I insert the data with a query like this one below, and it doesnt actually insert into the database, the page reloads and thats it. here is the result from `print_r()` and `var_dump()`. The actual query function is below. What can be the issue? I'm thinking it can be the text type overflow of some sort. But I cant figure it out, thanks for your help

`print_r()` Result:

```
insert into professor(name,department,rating,easiness,textbook,course,curve,comment)values('Cherry, Mark','HUMANITIES','8','8','yes','PHIL 3311','no','Go to class. He doesn't require it but it will make the difference between an A or a B. It's very difficult to do anything without being in class. He gives all the answers you need so long as you show up. He's a very good teacher and I would recommend him to someone else')
```

`var_dump()` Result:

```
string(424) "insert into professor(name,department,rating,easiness,textbook,course,curve,comment)values('Cherry, Mark','HUMANITIES','8','8','yes','PHIL 3311','no','Go to class. He doesn't require it but it will make the difference between an A or a B. It's very difficult to do anything without being in class. He gives all the answers you need so long as you show up. He's a very good teacher and I would recommend him to someone else')" bool(false)
```

Here is my code:

```
function processadd()
{
    $name =htmlentities($_POST['prof']);
    $department =htmlentities($_POST['depart']);
    $rating =htmlentities($_POST['Rating']);
    $easy=htmlentities($_POST['Easiness']);
    $textbook =htmlentities($_POST['Book']);
    $course =htmlentities($_POST['course']);
    $curve =htmlentities($_POST['curve']);
    $comment =htmlentities($_POST['comment']);
    if($course == "" || $comment == "")
    {
        print"<div class=error><h3> Empty Fields exist!, please fill out completely</h3></div>";
    }
    else
    {
    $db = adodbConnect();
    $query = "insert into professor(name,department,rating,easiness,textbook,course,curve,comment)values('$name','$department','$rating','$easy','$textbook','$course','$curve','$comment')";
    $result = $db -> Execute($query);
    }
    print_r($query);
    print_r($result);
    print"<br>";
    print"<br>";
    print"<br>";
    var_dump($query);
    var_dump($result);

}
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: nothing goes into the database, just the page reloaded

Comment: Can u try this `
$name"` instead of single quotes. You have a escape character in your variable may be that is the problem

Comment: so like "$name" with no single quotes?

Comment: yes! as the two answer point out the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely in the comment. It looks like you don't escape the ' s throughout the comment. Try inserting this statement:

```
insert into professor(name,department,rating,easiness,textbook,course,curve,comment)
values('Cherry, Mark','HUMANITIES','8','8','yes','PHIL 3311','no','Go to class. He doesn\'t require it but it will make the difference between an A or a B. It\'s very difficult to do anything without being in class. He gives all the answers you need so long as you show up. He\'s a very good teacher and I would recommend him to someone else');
```

Comment: Do you know how I can protect myself from this happening? like a pregmatch or maybe a htmlentities like function that can prevent this? because comments might have this.

Comment: You should look at converting the strings to hex strings. You can also use several encoding functions, the simplest of which is htmlspecialchars, however, if you encode (instead of hex) you have to decode on the way out of the database.

Answer (score 0):

Though you don't specify the error you're receiving, I'm guessing that it has to do with not-escaping the quotes in your query, specifically (but not limited to), the `comment` column.

For example, the column in your sample is:

> Go to class. He doesn't require it but it will make the difference
>   between an A or a B. It's very difficult to do anything without being
>   in class. He gives all the answers you need so long as you show up.
>   He's a very good teacher and I would recommend him to someone else

This text includes several single-quotes, which will break your SQL query and give you an error.

You're using [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/htmlentities) on each column's input, however, this does not prevent SQL injection; and, by default, `htmlentities` also doesn't convert single-quotes.

I don't know what MySQL library your database class is implementing, but you may want to try using the library's escaping functions.

For instance, if you're using the older `mysql_` functions, use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) instead of `htmlentities()` for each value. On the other hand, if you're using the more-recommended [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) classes, convert your query to be a prepared statement instead.

Comment: Do you know how I can protect myself from this ?

Comment: @user1902588 In 100% seriousness, do not attempt to write your own sanitization function. Each MySQL library available through PHP has a built-in method that sanitizes user-input, I highly recommend using those (it will also save you a lot of work). I can point you in the direction regarding "which functions" and even give you sample-code, just let me know which library you're using (MySQL, MySQLi, PDO, etc).

Comment: myphpadmin is what I'am using

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a user-interface into your database; the "library" I'm referring to is the code you're using in your project. If you're not sure what this is, one tip would be to look at the method `$db->Execute()` calls. If it's `mysql_query()`, you're using the older MySQL library; if it calls something different, well, it'll depend what the class extends in that case.

Comment: $db = adodbConnect(); this is what I have adodb5 library

Comment: @user1902588 Yes, that's how you assign your database variable, but the "object" that `adodbConnect()` method returns is what we're interested in. Regardless, as it's using a direct query (with no variables), we can assume it's using the older MySQL code. In that case, move the `$db = adodbConnect();` line to the top of your function and then update each `htmlentities()` to `mysql_real_escape_string()`. That should fix the problem. The reason we move `$db...` to the top is `mysql_real_escape_string()` needs an established connection in order to work.

Comment: $db = NewADOConnection('mysql'); here it is, im sorry for not knowing this

Comment: @user1902588 Though `NewADOConnection()` is not a built-in PHP function (so I have no idea what it does), a Google search led me to a few different scripts with it. Each of them show the `mysql` version to use the older MySQL library - *so*, again, try what I mentioned in my previous comment. Move `$db = adodbConnect();` to the top of your function and change all `htmlentities()` calls to `mysql_real_escape_string()` calls and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: it worked! thank you for your expertise and time, im doing this project to practice over my winter break and maybe one day reach your level!